# How to copy a directory with Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I've been playing around with Webpack to try and understand how it works but no matter what I do it never seems to do what I expect it to considering what the documentation and numerous videos seem to say.

As a first step to accomplishing my end goal, I simply want to copy all the files in the `./src` directory to the `./dist` directory, maintaining the full folder structure. After a bit of digging it seems what I need is something like this in the rules for my `webpack.config.js` (I currently only have html, css and js files in the source directory for testing purposes):

```
test: /\.(html|js|css)$/,
use: [
    {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
    }
]
```

Now in my `entry.js` file which is in the root directory I have this:

```
function requireAll (r) { r.keys().forEach(r); }
requireAll(require.context('./src/', true, /\.(html|js|css)$/));
```

...because from my understanding I need to import all the files I want to process into my entry file so they can then be placed into the new directory using `file-loader`.

With this setup, running webpack creates a dist folder like this:

```
dist/
    chunk.js     <-- (the output filename set in my webpack config)
    entry.js     <-- (an exact duplicate of the entry file)
```

This is obviously not what I want. I don't know whether I just need to tweak my setup or if I'm doing this completely wrong.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the [copy webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin).

`npm install --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin`

Edit your `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
    //Add a plugin declaration at the begining of file
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
    
    //...
    
    //search (or create) the plugin array. 
    plugins: [
        // ...
        // Add your plugin
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                
            // Copy directory contents to {output}/to/directory/
            //{ from: 'from/directory', to: 'to/directory' },
            { from: 'src', to: 'dist' },
        ]
      ],
```

There is a lot of simple [examples](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#examples) in documentation

edit syntax with Webpack5 is:

```js
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "./src/dir", to: "to/dir" }
            ],
        })
    ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin):

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

In Webpack **version 5** (current version) you can edit your *webpack.config.js* file, adding:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "./src/my-directory", to: "my-directory" }
            ],
        })
    ],
    ...
}
```

---

copy-webpack-plugin [Documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#readme)

Comment: That worked for me - I wanted to be able to use an existing svg sprite in my index.html file, and went down multiple rabbit holes trying to find a solution before coming across this.

Answer (score -5):

The purpose of webpack is that you should never have to copy files yourself like what you are saying. For example if you are trying to copy from './src' to './dist' you have already taken a bad wrong turn. :P Google around for some "web pack starter projects". And let one of those get you a working configuration. Then go from there, and build up. Starting from scratch will be a bit tricky. If you do have a good reason to copy files there is a webpack plugin i can tell you about for that, but i don't think you will need it.

Here's a file that uses plugins (my project):

https://github.com/Clay-Ferguson/meta64/blob/master/src/main/resources/public/webpack.config.js

I'm not using the 'file copy' plugin but i am using the 'webpack-shell-plugin' which is powerful because it can let you run any script you want before and/or after builds.

Comment: Well I guess the specific aspect of the intended webpack model that I don't understand is how it seems that everything has to be configured around an html file where all the assets will eventually be included. This makes sense for an SPA. However, suppose I don't want to use an html file at all, but instead want to use a number of Pug (Jade) templates. I'm trying to make a complete website, but I want to use things like Pug, Stylus, and Vue. How does that work with webpack?

Comment: The basic purpose of webpack revolves around the fact that most modern apps ARE SPAs, or at least have so many JS files that it becomes desirable to have all the JS bundled into one single file so the browser doesn't have to make many requests for each JS file. They later added support for retrieving HTML, CSS, etc directly from teh bundle file. But think of webpack mainly as a JS bundler so make your app only have a single JS file. If that isn't what you want, webpack is not for you maybe.

Comment: I just want to comment that there are legitimate use cases for copying files, such as when integrating your SPA with legacy assets or data files.